# Does my heater have an air filter?

Tags: furnace, heater, air-filter

I just moved in here, and it's time to use the heater. But looks like there's no actual screw on it, and I cannot open it. As you can see in the pictures, looks like there's no filter as well. How could I clean it or add filter over it? or I should just leave it as it is? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does the owners manual say?

Comment: Thanks @Ack I found one but not exactly the same one: https://rexel-cdn.com/Products/32B0A489-1A00-448F-9E84-0A4FC4CCCA63/32B0A489-1A00-448F-9E84-0A4FC4CCCA63.pdf . I have already sent an email to kings electric

Comment: There should be a filter, if there is no filter the heat exchanger loads up with dust , the dust can create extra heat and make the exchanger to fail. If a package unit ac/heat “Freon” based the evaporator gets plugged up and will not heat in the winter and freezes up in the summer.

Comment: Looks like plain old crude as a sledgehammer electric resistance - dust will be burnt off and the remains blown out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally took the grill off! Two screws on it were super to be found, those are at right and left side but between grids. Turn on flushlight of your phone to find it. Also, I checked with king electric, no air filter can be installed on it. But at least you can clean it once you get it opened.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Good call @ FreeMan . Updated!

Comment: Be sure that the circuit breaker supplying that is turned off, or you may get a nasty shock while cleaning it.